# Move transaction to Different Nonce, Keep signatures

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis, safe-core-sdk

Setup is as follows:

nonce=1: 2/8 approved

nonce=2: 8/8 approved

I want to do the tx at nonce=2 before nonce=1 but I don't want to recreate the TX and set the nonce because then I need to wrangle 8 signatures again.

Is there any way (off-chain is also fine) to move a tx to a different nonce but keep the signatures associated with that tx/call-data? Is there some other way to do this or mechanisms that can generally enable this capability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Moving" the signatures to another tx with different nonce it's impossible, and it would be a really critical security issue. You need to sign everything again or create a dummy tx with `nonce=1` and execute it first